# ajax to refresh stats counter after $.get command

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax call appended to a link as such:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='$.get(
       "projects.php",{
       cmd: "unpublish",
       id: "<?php echo $row_projects['id']; ?>" } ,
       function(data){
            $("#published_<?php echo $row_projects['id']; ?>").html(data);
            count();
       }
    );'>Unpublish</a>
```

Furthermore, I have a counter that shows how many projects have been `published` via:

```
function count() {
    $('#refresh-me').load('stats_counter.php?table=projects');
}
```

I want to be able to, refresh or recall `count();` after the ajax commend goes through. I have tried putting it after the part where I refresh a `<span>` with the project status. But this doesnt work.

Comment: how is it not working? what you've got right now looks like it should work... `count()` would be called when the .get()'s success handler (`function(data) ...`) kicks in.

Comment: also just a tip but you might want to move this out of the onclick since it will make your code a little cleaner and easier to read

Comment: its very odd indeed because I am doing a similar thing with my delete command, but it is as @tom suggested, not `onclick` and it works

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="onclick1();">Unpublish</a>
<script>
function onclick1(){
$.get(
           "projects.php",{
       cmd: "unpublish",
   id: "<?php echo $row_projects['id']; ?>" } ,       function(data){
        $("#published_<?php echo $row_projects['id']; ?>").html(data);
        count();
   }
);
}
</script>
```